# BBj SQL engine: Case insensitive search with SQL LIKE

Tags: sql, database, bbj

I'm using the following query to search by `TITLE` in the `CDSTORE` database, but the search is not case insensitive. How to make the search case insensitive? I thought about using the `LOWER` verb but I guess it is not defined by the [BBj SQL engine](https://documentation.basis.cloud/BASISHelp/WebHelp/b3odbc/sql_grammar_bbjds.htm?Highlight=sql).

```sql
SELECT TITLE, MUSICTYPE FROM CDINVENTORY WHERE TITLE LIKE '%s%' ORDER BY MUSICTYPE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe BBj doesn't support the `LOWER` verb, but instead, you could use the integrated [CVS](https://documentation.basis.cloud/BASISHelp/WebHelp/commands/bbj-commands/cvs_function_bbj.htm) Function to the exact same thing. The following should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT TITLE, MUSICTYPE FROM CDINVENTORY WHERE cvs(TITLE,8) LIKE '%s%' ORDER BY MUSICTYPE
```